# Is there a way to enter Highchart series data without eval?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, eval

I have been working on getting data into a highchart graph with much difficulty.

Eventually I had to go with using eval(data).

Is there a better way to do this?

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G6jrU/1/)

```
$(function () {
    var test = "[[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 08), 45.95],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 28), 19.95]]"; 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{
            data: eval(test)
        }]
    });
});
```

### UPDATE 1

My actual objective is to pass a JSON object into a function (as shown below) then get the required strings and pass them to the series input.

The following is still not working.

```
function showPriceChart(priceData) {

    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(priceData);
    var pricePrices = [ json.pricePrices ];

            // This works if I use eval below
            // var pricePrices = '['+json.pricePrices+']';


    /// Other chart config goes here

    series: [{
            name: 'Retailer Price',
            data: pricePrices
        }, {
            name: 'RRP',
            data: rrpPrices
        }]
    });
    }
```

Here is the JSON object from php using print_r():

```
{"pricePrices":"[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 8), 67],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 28), 29]","salePrices":"[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 8), ],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 28), ]","rrpPrices":"[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 8), 67],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 28), 67]"}
```

Comment: Your JSON object from PHP is wrong.  That's a javascript array of string keys and **string** values.  You want an array of string keys with **array** values.  Show your PHP code.

Comment: shouldn't json_encode be used ?

Answer (score 0):

you were really close from your goal.
The following is working :

(http://jsfiddle.net/G6jrU/3/)

```
$(function () {

    var test =[ [ Date.UTC(2013, 4, 08),  45.95 ], 
                [ Date.UTC(2013, 5, 28), 19.95  ]  ];


    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{ data : test }]

    });
});
```

Rq : You might use JSON to serialize/unserialize data if you need to.

Comment: Thanks - that indeed worked for the example - but does not seem to work when I try with the actual data (see update in question) - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `Date.UTC()` function, so you need to use eval. How about passing numbers(timestamps in milliseconds) instead of that functions? So, your JSON should look this way:

```
{
 "pricePrices":[1367971200000, 67],[1372377600000, 29],
 "salePrices":[1367971200000, ],[1372377600000, ], //where are values ?!
 "rrpPrices":[1367971200000, 67],[1372377600000, 67] //without extra '"'!! 
}
```

Also, there is some missing values for second series, where are they?