# eval data in json pass in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to pass json data in jquery for this i try this

**UPDATE**

WITH SERIALIZE OBJECT

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string select()
        {
            SMSEntities d = new SMSEntities();



             List<string> name = new List<string>();

            //string data1 = "[";

            var mdata = new SMSEntities().selectdata()
            .Select(s => new { s.name }).ToArray().Distinct();

            //foreach (var c in mdata)
            //{

            //    data1 += "'" + c.name + "',";
            //    name.Add(c.name);
            //    // res += c.month;
            //}

            //data1 = data1.Substring(0, data1.Length - 1);
            //data1 += "]";


            var score = new SMSEntities().selectdata().Select(s => new { s.name, s.Salary });


            // data2 = "[";
            //foreach (var b in score)
            //{
            //    data2 += "{name:'" + b.name + "',data:[" + b.Salary + "]},";
            //}


            //data2 = data2.Substring(0, data2.Length - 1);
            //data2 += "]";

            var json1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mdata);
           var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(score);
           var result = new { data = json1, data2 = json2 };
          return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

now mdata return data like this

```
[{"name":"abc_name"},{"name":"xyz_name"},{"name":"def_name"},{"name":"ght_name"},{"name":"lmn_name"},{"name":"hh_name"}]
```

and score return like this

```
[{"name":"abc_name","Salary":"34000"},{"name":"xyz_name","Salary":"23000"},{"name":"def_name","Salary":"1000"},{"name":"ght_name","Salary":"45000"},{"name":"lmn_name","Salary":"34000"},{"name":"hh_name","Salary":"33000"}]
```

and jquery without eval

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/select",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,

                success: function (result) {


                    var data1 = result.d.split('*')[0];
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data1));
                    console.log(data1);
                    alert(data1);

                    var data2 = result.d.split("*")[1];
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data2));
                    console.log(data2);

                    alert(data2);


                    var od = JSON.stringify(result);
                    debugger;
                    alert("1");
                    var obj = JSON.parse(od);
                    debugger;
                    alert(od);
                    // alert(obj);



                    Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories:data1,
                            //categories: [
                            //    'Jan',
                            //    'Feb',
                            //    'Mar',
                            //    'Apr',
                            //    'May',
                            //    'Jun',
                            //    'Jul',
                            //    'Aug',
                            //    'Sep',
                            //    'Oct',
                            //    'Nov',
                            //    'Dec'
                            //],
                            crosshair: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                            shared: true,
                            useHTML: true
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },

                        //series: [{
                        //    name: 'Tokyo',
                        //    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

                        //}, {
                        //    name: 'New York',
                        //    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

                        //}, {
                        //    name: 'London',
                        //    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

                        //}, {
                        //    name: 'Berlin',
                        //    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

                        //}]
                        //series: [{

                        //    data: eval(data2)
                        //}]
                        series: data2,
                    });

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

now when i use serialize object data in highchart not display .. also series which is returned is correct according to valid json .. also there is no error when i check F12

Comment: Looks like you are getting exception in `selectdata` method.

Comment: @Leopard check update please

Comment: You don't need to `JSON.stringify` data you can directly use it or if required you can `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: ok i remove JSON.stringify and direclty use this but when i remove eval then data display wrongly in chart.. @Leopard

Comment: Why you don't want to use `eval` ?

Comment: because i dont know what is eval.. i just search and paste. and i heard eval is include in bad practice

Comment: Than return a `json` string from server.

Comment: how>?? @Leopard will you please help

Comment: i think i already return json from code

Comment: He cannot use the native `JSON` object because what he has is not JSON, as simple as that. (Why using actual JSON is not an option, that's another question.)

Comment: means @ÁlvaroGonzález .. ??

Comment: JSON is a data format of its own, not just another name for JavaScript.

Comment: your data is not a valid json.

Comment: @Leopard so how to get valid json

Comment: @superuser don't build json yourself by adding `{` and `[` Rather use `javascriptSerializer`

Comment: @Leopard CHECK update code with javascriptSerializer  now how i can do with removing brackets?

Comment: @superuser no need to surround `data` with `[` simply use score object and pass it to `var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(score, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings());`

Comment: @Leopard check update last lines.. but when i use this the format i want is not display ..

Comment: @superuser you are still creating string yourself do it as i said in above comment.

Comment: @Leopard now check updated code i done with this but there is also mdata how i return this and also i remove eval but chart not display ..

Comment: Try this `var json1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(score);`

Comment: @Leopard check update please..

Comment: @superuser first tell me is `score` returning ok now  ?

Comment: yess..@Leopard.........

Comment: now how i split data in jquery @Leopard

Comment: How the `data` is returned as whole don't show separate show as whole than i will be able to tell you.

Comment: but in chart i want to display mdata in x axis and score data which is fill in chart..

Comment: @superuser please accept my answer as correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `json` data to ajax call and that will be used in chart. You can use `JavaScriptSerliazer` to make `json` data.

```
var json1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mdata);
var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(score);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data in jquery so your javascript code should be like this-

```
     $(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET", // This Should be GET instead of POST
                     url: "WebForm1.aspx/select",                   
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     async: true,
                     success: function (result) {
                         var data1 = result.data1;
                         var data2 = result.data2;
                         .......
                 });
}
             });
```

and your code should be like this-

```
[WebMethod]
public static string select() {
    SMSEntities d = new SMSEntities();
    List < string > name = new List < string > ();
    string data1 = "[";

    var mdata = new SMSEntities().selectdata()
        .Select(s => new {
            s.name
        }).ToArray().Distinct();
    foreach(var c in mdata) {

        data1 += '{"name" : "' + c.name + '"},';
        name.Add(c.name);
    }
    data1 = data1.Substring(0, data1.Length - 1);
    data1 += "]";

    var score = new SMSEntities().selectdata().Select(s => new {
        s.name, s.Salary
    });
    string data2 = "[";
    foreach(var b in score) {
        data2 += '{"name": "' + b.name + '" , "data" :[' + b.Salary + ']},';
    }
    data2 = data2.Substring(0, data2.Length - 1);
    data2 += "]";

    return '{"data1": '+ data1 + ',"data2":' + data2 + '}';
}
```

and in ajax success function, result will give you json data.

Comment: what about eval

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763431/is-there-a-way-to-enter-highchart-series-data-without-eval) for eval

Comment: You don't need use eval you can directly use  **series: data2** in your highchart.

Comment: @Ashvin when i use direct then data in highchart not correctly display

Comment: @superuser use data2 inside Brackets like **series:[{data:data2}]** and see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216090/to-pass-dynamic-json-array-to-highcharts-pie-chart) for more details.